# Basic C Pointer and Functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

Im trying to figure out what the function declarations mean:

```
int *f();
```

and

```
int (*g)();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix operators such as function-call `()` have higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so

```
T *f();
```

reads as

```
   f     -- f
   f()   -- is a function (() binds before *)
  *f()   -- returning a pointer
T *f();  -- to T (for some type T)
```

If you want to force `*` to bind before `()`, you must explicitly group with parentheses, so

```
T (*g)();
```

reads as

```
    g     -- g
  (*g)    -- is a pointer
  (*g)()  -- to a function
T (*g)(); -- returning T.
```

The rule is similar for arrays: `T *a[N]` is an array of pointer to `T`, whereas `T (*p)[N]` is a pointer to an array of `T`.

Answer (score 6):

```
int *f();
```

The above line is the declaration of a function `f` that has an unspecified number of parameters and that returns an `int *`.

```
int (*g)();
```

The above line is the declaration of a pointer `g` to a function that has an unspecified number of parameters and that returns an `int`.

Comment: does `int (*f())` change anything?

Comment: @calccrypto  same as declaration as `int *f();`

Comment: @calccrypto, that's just the same as your `int *f()` example.  It just has an extra set of parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the other correct answers here, I thought I'd mention that [`cdecl(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cdecl) is a handy tool for deciphering these sorts of declarations:

```
$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain int *f();
declare f as function returning pointer to int
cdecl> explain int (*g)();
declare g as pointer to function returning int
```

`cdecl` may already be installed on your machine, or you can use it via a handy web interface at http://cdecl.org.

Answer (score 3):

`f` is a function, returning `int*` and `g` is a pointer to function returning `int`.